# Quantum Theory and Time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, spacetime, time, time-dilation

I read somewhere that quantum theory requires absolute time and not a dynamic time as described in relativity. Can anyone confirm this and further describe in laymen's terms what quantum theorists believe about time and why it requires it to be absolute. Also as we have so much evidence that Einstein’s view of time is correct how can quantum theorists rationalise this position ?

Comment: Either you or your source got some things mixed up. The original version of quantum mechanics was non-relativistic, but that was soon corrected and modern QM (aka Quantum Field Theory, QFT) is fully compatible with special relativity and does not require absolute time or space.

Comment: This is not what ‘Quanta’ the magazine have to say on the subject. See this article by Natalie Wolchover, senior editor. https://www.quantamagazine.org/quantum-gravitys-time-problem-20161201/

Comment: That's a pop science article, and Natalie Wolchover is a journalist, not a scientist, and in this case she's severely misrepresented things. QFT is fully compatible with special relativity, as you can see in any textbook on the subject, or by looking at Steven Weinberg's article https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9702027.pdf (e.g. pages 4 and 5). (Weinberg was a Nobel prize winning physicist, not a journalist). The difficulty in quantum gravity is reconciling quantum mechanics with *general* relativity, not special relativity.

Comment: OP, are you talking about special relativity, or general relativity, or what?

Comment: Eric Smith, there is no relativistic description of measurement in QFT. If disagree, please provide the QFT relativistic account for the EPR scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with those who down-voted the question. Time is indeed special in QM, and unlike relativity it is not just yet another coordinate there. Quantum theory is defined as temporal evolution in Hilbert space, where time acts as a sort of external parameter that just tells one how far one is into evolution. Formally you already see this from the fact that time is not an observable in Dirac's sense and hence does not a corresponding operator (unlike spatial coordinates, which are perfectly good observables with their operators). Time is a parameter that "ticks" and everything else evolves on its background. Things get even messier once phenomena related quantum measurements are taken into account. Here time even acquires a direction distinguishing past from future, and this has no straightforward correspondence in relativity.

Very smart people have indeed managed to put QM in accordance with special relativity, (but had to make some serious sacrifices on the way; to the point that Dirac himself, who started the whole business, refused to accept the final result as fully satisfactory) but without similar success when it come to general relativity. I believe the central problem here is time again. Taking time the way QM understands it, i.e. as something that just keeps "ticking", how does one understand what goes on at the surface worse so inside a black hole?

Comment: It's not clear that OP means "general relativity" when OP refers to "dynamic time as described in relativity." As stated in several comments, QM is perfectly compatible with special relativity. Because OP's question is unclear and lacks focus, I downvoted. I think this is a valid reason to downvote (per the help center and meta discussions).

Comment: @hft:  I think it's important to draw a distinction here.  This answer is perfectly coorect:  QM is incompatible with relativity.  The comments are also correct:  QFT *is* compatible with relativity.

Comment: @WillO I don't agree with your characterization. I think it is more appropriate and more of a modern viewpoint to say that QFT *is* QM. That is, QFT is the quantum mechanics of fields. I you like, QFT can still be described in terms of a Schrodinger equation and a Hamiltonian operator acting on a state, but the state is a functional of the fields. The key point is that we *can* do QM where the particle number is not fixed, and this is really all that QFT is.